# OGR Error when saving selected features as new shapefile

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

I got this geodatabase directly from a county source - is it possible they made it so nothing can be edited? The ogr error says:

> "Export to vector file failed. Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR
>   error: Failed to create file DNR.shp: Permission denied)"

Comment: More like you can't write to the directory you picked